# Positioning two graphs relative to each other inside a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I have two graphs within the same tikzpicture, I would like the second to be placed to the right of the first, but currently they just perfectly overlay each other. I tried placing them both on the same path and using move-to commands before each graph, but this appears to have no effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (-1, 0) graph[circular placement, radius=4cm,
           empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}] {
        { subgraph I_n [V={a,b,c,d,e,f}] };
        e -- b -- d -- c -- a -- f;
        a -- e;
    } (1, 0) graph[circular placement, radius=4cm,
           empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}] {
        { subgraph I_n [V={a,b,c,d,e,f}] };
        e -- b -- d -- c -- a -- f;
        a -- e;
        { [edges=dashed]
            a -- b -- c -- e -- f;
            d -- e;
            b -- f;
            d -- f;
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use two scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use shifted scopes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-1,0)}]
    \graph[circular placement, radius=4cm,
           empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}] {
        { subgraph I_n [V={a,b,c,d,e,f}] };
        e -- b -- d -- c -- a -- f;
        a -- e;
    };
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
    \graph[circular placement, radius=4cm,
           empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}] {
        { subgraph I_n [V={a,b,c,d,e,f}] };
        e -- b -- d -- c -- a -- f;
        a -- e;
        { [edges=dashed]
            a -- b -- c -- e -- f;
            d -- e;
            b -- f;
            d -- f;
        }
    };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity that although the `pgfmanual` says `graph` path command can be used anywhere on a path, currently the first node in the first node chain of a graph is always (not sure) positioned at `(0,0)`.

> In order to construct a graph, you should use the `graph` path command, which can be used anywhere on a path at any place where you could also use a command like, say, `plot` or `--`.
>
> pgfmanual v3.1.9a, sec. 19.3.1 "*The Graph Command*"

Since the `<options>` in `graph[<options>]` are executed within an extra scope, you can

- use `graph[/tikz/shift={<coordinate>}, ...]` to manually shift the graph
- or define a new graph option to automatically move to the last coordinate seen on path:

  ```tex
  \tikzgraphsset{
    auto shift/.style={
      /tikz/xshift=\tikz@lastx,
      /tikz/yshift=\tikz@lasty
    }
  }
  ```

  One can even append `auto shift` to style `/tikz/graphs/every graph` to make life easier.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\makeatletter
\tikzgraphsset{
  auto shift/.style={
    /tikz/xshift=\tikz@lastx,
    /tikz/yshift=\tikz@lasty
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Default, graph starts from the origin.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \path (1,1) graph {a -> b -> c};
\end{tikzpicture}

Using \verb|/tikz/shift={(1,1)}|\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \path (1,1) graph[/tikz/shift={(1,1)}] {a -> b -> c};
\end{tikzpicture}

Using newly defined option \verb|auto shift|\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \path (1,1) graph[auto shift] {a -> b -> c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]